# How to exclude row not distinct by 2 fields

Tags: t-sql

I have some code, which returns not expected result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
T.Field_1
T.Field_2
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ...
    FROM

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        ...
    FROM
) AS T
GROUP BY T.Field_1, T.Field_2
```

result:

[image]

Line 3 must be absent because it is not distinct by Field_1 and Field_2. How to do this with some SQL features?

Comment: You do not need distinct, but if you had a third column you would need to provide a SQL aggregate function such as Max() on it. Group by col1, col2 means exactly what you said.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: *Line 3 must be absent because it is not distinct by Field_1 and Field_2* it is distinct  by Field_1 and Field_2. `distinct` operates on the combination of the 2 columns.

Comment: Your logic isn't clear. The results you have are exactly what you asked for. Do you mean that you only want each value to occur once, whether that's in `Field_1` or `Field_2`? Or do you want something else?

Answer (score 0):

If `Field_1` is the only column that has to be unique and you just want the first record for every unique `Field_1` value then below is a way to accomplish that.

```
CREATE TABLE #table (Field_1 VARCHAR(MAX), Field_2 VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO
    #table
VALUES
    ('Item A', ''),
    ('Item B', ''),
    ('Item B', 'Item A'),
    ('Item C', ''),
    ('Item D', 'Item A')

SELECT DISTINCT
    [b].[Field_1], [b].[Field_2]
FROM
    #table AS [a]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1
        [Field_1], [Field_2]
    FROM
        #table AS [b]
    WHERE
        [a].[Field_1] = [b].[Field_1]
) AS [b]


DROP TABLE #table
```